# Extracting elements of nested list by contained value using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have a nested list where each nested list has the same elements but not in the same order and the elements are not named explicitly but do have a name value within the list.

As you can see in the structure the list containing the 'Date' field appears at the second position in the first list and the third position in the second list, so I can't extract at a position.

I would like to extract the lists where `name :` is `Date` and keep the value associated with it, using the `purrr` package.

STRUCTURE

```
dplyr::glimpse(my_list)
List of 2
 $ :List of 10
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "MIME-Version"
  .. ..$ value: chr "1.0"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "Date"
  .. ..$ value: chr "Wed, 13 Feb 2019 15:20:40 -0800"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "References"
  .. ..$ value: chr "<CAE1g-C7AmC3zoJRG_UgdwwkkSiJMuEuDYLU1j4ni0MZJXNrGNQ@mail.gmail.com>"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "In-Reply-To"
  .. ..$ value: chr "<CAE1g-C7AmC3zoJRG_UgdwwkkSiJMuEuDYLU1j4ni0MZJXNrGNQ@mail.gmail.com>"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "Message-ID"
  .. ..$ value: chr "<CAPApPh+WZszKg_bjQBPrS8TOvLA23hQkaa9Hocb_cgrQYs2R1w@mail.gmail.com>"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "Subject"
  .. ..$ value: chr "Re:"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "From"
  .. ..$ value: chr ""
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "To"
  .. ..$ value: chr ""
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "Cc"
  .. ..$ value: chr ""
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "Content-Type"
  .. ..$ value: chr "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"000000000000f3d8810581cec99d\""
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "MIME-Version"
  .. ..$ value: chr "1.0"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "Message-ID"
  .. ..$ value: chr "<CAPApPh+THbnCg2e5WmKEwQwHEEjKDHq3V6LkYV9oL88DbHE9Pg@mail.gmail.com>"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "Date"
  .. ..$ value: chr "Wed, 13 Feb 2019 12:18:32 -0800"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "Subject"
  .. ..$ value: chr ""
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "From"
  .. ..$ value: chr "Daniel Seneca <senecad@gene.com>"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "To"
  .. ..$ value: chr "Daniel Seneca <seneca.daniel@gene.com>"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "Content-Type"
  .. ..$ value: chr "multipart/mixed; boundary=\"000000000000f11ad10581cc3e85\""
```

DATA

```
my_list <-list(list(list(name = "MIME-Version", value = "1.0"), list(name = "Date", value = "Wed, 13 Feb 2019 15:20:40 -0800"), list(name = "References", value = "<CAE1g-C7AmC3zoJRG_UgdwwkkSiJMuEuDYLU1j4ni0MZJXNrGNQ@mail.gmail.com>"), list(name = "In-Reply-To", value = "<CAE1g-C7AmC3zoJRG_UgdwwkkSiJMuEuDYLU1j4ni0MZJXNrGNQ@mail.gmail.com>"),list(name = "Message-ID", value = "<CAPApPh+WZszKg_bjQBPrS8TOvLA23hQkaa9Hocb_cgrQYs2R1w@mail.gmail.com>"), list(name = "Subject", value = "Re:"), list(name = "From", value = ""),list(name = "To", value = ""),list(name = "Cc", value = ""),list(name = "Content-Type", value = "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"000000000000f3d8810581cec99d\"")),
               list(list(name = "MIME-Version", value = "1.0"), list(name = "Message-ID",value = "<CAPApPh+THbnCg2e5WmKEwQwHEEjKDHq3V6LkYV9oL88DbHE9Pg@mail.gmail.com>"),list(name = "Date",value = "Wed, 13 Feb 2019 12:18:32 -0800"), list(name = "Subject", value = ""), list(name = "From",value = "Daniel Seneca <senecad@gene.com>"), list(name = "To", value = "Daniel Seneca <seneca.daniel@gene.com>"),list(name = "Content-Type", value = "multipart/mixed; boundary=\"000000000000f11ad10581cc3e85\"")))
```

Comment: You can use `pluck` function from `purrr`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/pluck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not define what the output is supposed to look like so we will assume that it should be a list of lists.  Remove the first layer using `flatten` as shown and then filter its elements using `keep`.

```
library(purrr)
my_list %>% 
  flatten %>%
  keep(~ .x$name == "Date")
```

In base R this could be written:

```
Filter(function(x) x$name == "Date", do.call("c", my_list))
```

Comment: I ended up using `my_list %>% modify_depth(1, ~ keep(., ~.x$name == "Date"))` as to maintain the list structure. But your answer worked perfectly.